# Splitting the contents of a tibble() that was built through web-scraping

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(date = c("3/31/19\n10:00 PM", "3/31/19\n11:30 PM", "4/1/19\n12:00 AM", "4/1/19\n11:00 PM", "4/1/19\n11:08 PM", "4/1/19\n11:08 PM", "4/2/19\n12:00 AM", "4/2/19\n12:30 AM")), .Names = ".", row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It gives me a date and time, within the same `<chr>` string. I have been mind-numbingly unable to split the date from the time. I've tried every combo of `str_split()`, the base `strsplit()`, `separate()`, and the `grep` family. How can I go from one column named `.`:

```
3/31/19\n10:00 PM
```

to two separate columns, named `date` & `time`? -

```
date       time
3/31/19    10:00 PM
```

Splitting on `\n` has yielded no results. Is this because the values are `<chr>`, and not simple strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single column in 'df' is named `.` , `rename` the column nam and then `sepaarate` it into two column with `sep` specified as `\n`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   rename(X1 = ".") %>%
   # if there are multiple columns, use rename_all
   #rename_all(~ paste0("X", seq_along(.))) %>% 
   separate(X1, into = c("date", "time"), sep="\n")
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#  date    time    
#  <chr>   <chr>   
#1 3/31/19 10:00 PM
#2 3/31/19 11:30 PM
#3 4/1/19  12:00 AM
#4 4/1/19  11:00 PM
#5 4/1/19  11:08 PM
#6 4/1/19  11:08 PM
#7 4/2/19  12:00 AM
#8 4/2/19  12:30 AM
```

---

With `base R`, we can use `read.csv` after replacing the `\n` with `,` and concatenating together with `\n`

```
out <- read.csv(text = paste(sub("\n", ",", df[[1]]), collapse="\n"), 
             header = FALSE, col.names = c("date", "time"))
```

Comment: Not a typo- when I scraped the data and converted to `tibble()`, that's what it gave me, oddly enough

Comment: @papelr   okay, you can specify the name in `tibble(Col = .)`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this...

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% separate ('.', c('Date', 'Time'), sep = '\n')
```

and it worked perfectly. Can you share the code you were trying that didn't work?